# How should I display getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I found some code online to access my webcam. It accesses the webcam but it doesn't display what it see's. I know this is normal because there is no html in the document but I was wondering how I could display the result. The code I found is:

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing a `video` tag in your HTML, used to "dump" the webcam's stream. Since it's not a good idea to reference the tag by its tag name (`video`), you should use an ID instead (for example, `#webcam`). Just create a video tag with that id:

```
<video id="webcam"></video>
```

Update your code, within `document.querySelector`, to reference your new tag:

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('#webcam'); // <- Here
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

Here's a working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nn7ku3sa/1/).

Also, remember to allow the web browser to use your webcam and microphone.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I tested it and it works. I will be using the code for mobile devices (android and ios). I don't know if that changes anything. Anyways, it worked on jsFiddle. Thanks again! Oh yeah, I almost forgot. For my app I'll need to capture videos and photos. If you could show me how to capture a photo and video and store it in a file it'd be great.

Comment: I tried it on an android device and it doesn't ask for the permission. Therefore it doesn't work (I'm just assuming that because it didn't ask for the permission it doesn't work but I don't know for sure.).

Comment: @TheodoreTremblot For your first comment, as it's another question, you should probably search some information on internet; if you're stuck with something, create another StackOverflow question, since it's not directly related to this one. Now, in response to your second comment, I've tried the JSFiddle on an Android device (4.4.4) with Chrome and Firefox. Could you please provide more information? For more information about compatibility, check [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream).

Comment: I tried it off an html compiler I had downloaded off the google play store. I tried on jsFiddle from my smartphone and  it worked. I'll do what you said for the first question.